# Creating an array of objects containing references

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers, reference

What is the best way to deal with the following situation?

Suppose that I have something that should behave like this

```
class Foo
    {
    public:
         Foo(Bar& bar):m_bar(bar){}
    private:
         Bar& m_bar;
    };
```

Foo:s must have a valid reference to Bar:s. Also different Foo:s needs different or the same Bar:s.

I want to store Foo:s in an array. However, since Foo will require a non-default constructor, it will not work.

I could create an array of pointers to Foo:s, but then I need to call new and delete for each object in that array.

I could define Foo like this instead

```
class Foo
    {
    public:
         void init(Bar& bar)
             {
             m_bar=&bar;
             }
    private:
         Bar* m_bar;
    };
```

, but then it is possible to create uninitialized Foo:s.

What about some sort of placement new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, sorry for my first answer I got the question wrong.
Here is a better solution I hope: you can create a `vector` of elements without default constructor like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class Foo 
{ 
public: 
    Foo(int& bar): m_pBar(bar)
    { } 

    Foo& operator=(const Foo& other)
    { m_pBar = other.m_pBar;  }

    int Get()
    { return m_pBar; }

private: 
    int& m_pBar; 
}; 


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int test[10]  = { 0 };

    vector<Foo> vect;
    for (int& i: test)
        vect.emplace_back(i);

    test[0] = 1;
    cout << vect[0].Get() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But if Foo also contains a BLOb which I do not want to copy?

Comment: I am not sure where you see the copying here. *Be careful about anticipated optimization* as well. First, the "copy" will probably be optimized by the compiler in a "move", second it's probably not that slow, third you may use a reference for Blob as well ...

Comment: Well, the assignment operator copies data from ´other´ into ´*this´. When I say BLOb, I mean something that might be some megs.

Comment: Then it is more than justified to use a smart pointer or reference for blob that will be light to copy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pointers still but instead of using raw pointers use unique_ptrs. These are available in c++11, but if you are using an older compiler you could use the boost implementation.

For example

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(unique_ptr<Bar> bar):m_pBar(bar){}
private:
  unique_ptr<Bar> m_pBar;
};
```

This way you don't have to worry about calling delete on your Bar objects as they are deleted once there are no more references to them.

Then you can use Foo like this

```
unique_ptr<Bar> pBar(new Bar());
Foo(pBar);
```

EDIT: Changed to use unique_ptr instead of shared_ptr and added example usage

Comment: I think `unique_ptr` would be preferable. There's no need to share the data among many threads.

Comment: agreed. I'll change my answer to reflect this.

Comment: it still causes new to be called for each object, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you'd still need to call new, changed my answer to show example

Comment: But I wanted an array of Foo:s and the class Foo unchanged. Do you mean unique_ptr<Foo> foos=new unique_ptr<Foo>[n]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I implemented a custom container with the following constructor:

```
template<class T>
template<class U,class V>
Array<T>::Array(unsigned int n,U source_iterator,const V& source_resource):memory(n*sizeof(T))
    {
    data=(T*)memory.pointerGet();
    unsigned int k;
    try
        {
        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
            {
            new(data+k)T(*source_iterator,source_resource);
            ++source_iterator;
            }
        }
    catch(...)
        {
        while(k>0)
             {
             k--;
             data[k].~T();
             }
        throw;
        }
    length=n;
    capacity=n;
}
```